# Multiple conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I have following table:

Employee ID Employee Status Date of Termination
1   A   NULL
2   A   NULL
3   I   1/1/2016
4   I   12/15/2016
5   I   1/1/2016

[image]

I would like to report on the following:

> - Number of current active employees - 2
> - Number of inactive employees - 3
> - Number of employees terminated in last one month - 2

This is the piece of code I used:

```
select 
case when employee_status='A' then count(employee_id) else '' end, 
case when employee_status='I' then count(employee_id) else '' end, 
case when employee_status='I' 
 then  
 (select count(employee_id) 
  from employee 
 where date_of_termination between '1/1/2016' and '2/1/2016') 
 else '' end 
 from employee
```

My result set is:

```
Active | Inactive | Inactive_last_month
     2 |        0 |                   0
     0 |        3 |                   2
```

I would like to achieve the following:

```
Active | Inactive | Inactive_last_month
     2 |        3 |                   2
```

Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible to simplify it using `SUM` :

```
select 
sum(case when employee_status='A' then 1 else 0 end) as active, 
sum(case when employee_status='I' then 1 else 0 end) as inactive, 
sum(case when employee_status='I' and date_of_termination between '1/1/2016' and '2/1/2016' then 1 else 0 end) as inactive_last_month
 from employee
```

Answer (score 0):

I woudl wrap the case satements in sum() function and also modify the ELSE part of the CASE Statement to be 0.

so it will look like something like this:

```
select 
SUM(case when employee_status='A' then count(employee_id) else 0 end) AS Active, 
SUM(case when employee_status='I' then count(employee_id) else 0 end) AS Inactive, 
SUM(case when employee_status='I' 
then  
 (select count(employee_id) 
  from employee 
 where date_of_termination between '1/1/2016' and '2/1/2016') 
 else 0 end) AS Inactive_last_month
 from employee
```

Comment: Thanks. There was an extra "Sum" in your query, which I edited and it woked fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous glad to have helped! I removed the extra SUM()

Answer (score 0):

You need to `SUM` up the number of rows that match each criteria:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_of_termination IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_of_termination IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inactive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_of_termination BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160201' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inactive_last_month
FROM
    Employee
```

I've ignored the `employee_status` column with the assumption that the date is sufficient to determine whether or not the employee is active/inactive - in which case that column probably shouldn't even exist in the table since it's duplicating data.

Comment: Some employees are rehires, who have different status, hence the column is needed. But the aggregation was helpful. Thanks.